# Switching between python versions for Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, eclipse, python-3, compatibility

I’m developing a multi-module project in Python. I’m new to GIS and my boss doesn’t have a strong technical background. I’ve been instructed to use the Arcpy module to do functions such as intersect. The project requirements state I need to use Python 3.3.
Is there a contradiction between using the Arcpy module and Python 3.3?
I’m using Liclipse (Eclipse styled for Python) and in one module use the [library lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) and in another use Arcpy. In properties, if I put the `python C:\Python33\python.exe` on top then lxml works but Arcpy doesn’t and if I put `pythonArcGis C:\Python27\...`  on top then Arcpy works and lxml doesn’t. I don’t really understand what’s going on…
[image: screen shot of Preferences in liclipse]
Questions:
Can Arcpy work with Python 3.3?
If yes, how do you get both Arcpy and lxml to work at the same time?
If no, then is it possible to launch only the module that uses Arcpy as Python 2.7?

Comment: @Vince that one says ArcGIS will only every work with 2.6, and I've proven that wrong because I've got it working with 2.7 (see picture above). Do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood.  Each release of Desktop is compatible with a specific 2.x Python.  ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3.x, but Desktop/Server does not.